# Can not connect Django to sql server

Tags: sql-server, django

I follow the steps from [( Microsoft help to connect SQL server to Django)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/mssql-django-samples/mssql-django-samples/) and then I receive this error "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'mssql' isn't an available database backend or couldn't be imported. Check the above exception. To use one of the built-in backends, use 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'"

- Python version is 3.10.11
- Django version is 3.2.19

## **steps:

## **

Create a Django project

```
$ django-admin startproject mysite
E
```

dit setting.py file
Go to `mysite/mysite/settings.py`
In DATABASE section, edit accrodingly. Make sure the DATABASE_NAME is exist in your SQL Server instance.

## settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "mssql",
        "NAME": "DATABASE_NAME",
        "USER": "USER_NAME",
        "PASSWORD": "PASSWORD",
        "HOST": "HOST_ADDRESS",
        "PORT": "1433",
        "OPTIONS": {"driver": "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server", 
        },
    },
}
```

Run Django project

## Windows

`py manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the django-mssql-backend python package? It is required for connecting to MSSQL. You may also need the pyodbc python package.

Comment: yes, I did. I use pyodbc package, sqlalchemy and also pymssql to connect Python. and that works but to connect Django any of these didn't work at all.